# Combine protobuf with python namespaced package in bazel

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, bazel

I am trying to set up Bazel on an existing project that consists of three applications in Python and Groovy, and a shared protobuf IDL.

For the Python applications, I currently have a custom command in `setup.py` that generates a Python module from the protobuf IDL. When generating the python module, I place it inside the application packages, so it can be imported like any other module in the application.

When trying to put the whole project under Bazel I'm struggeling to find out how to deal with the generated python module. `protoc` will only generate a single file. In order to put the file in a package, I need to create a directory structure and move the file into place. Some googling has lead me to a solution that combines some `pkg_tar` rules to create a tarball with the correct layout, but I can't figure out how to make the jump to making this into a python library.

The files are laid out like this:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── protobuf
│   └── messages.proto
└── python
    └── ibidem
        ├── __init__.py
        └── codetanks
            ├── __init__.py
            └── domain
                └── __init__.py
```

I want the generated module to be placed in `ibidem/codetanks/domain`, so that it can be imported with `from ibidem.codetanks.domain import messages_pb2`.

My current `BUILD` file:

```
load("@build_stack_rules_proto//python:python_proto_library.bzl", "python_proto_library")
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar", "pkg_deb")

proto_library(
    name = "messages_proto",
    srcs = ["protobuf/messages.proto"],
)

python_proto_library(
    name = "messages_python_proto",
    deps = [":messages_proto"],
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "python_messages_tarball",
    strip_prefix = "protobuf/",
    package_dir = "ibidem/codetanks/domain",
    srcs = [":messages_python_proto"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "python_domain_files",
    srcs = glob([
        "python/**/*.py",
    ]),
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "python_domain_tarball",
    strip_prefix = "python/",
    srcs = [":python_domain_files"],
)

# This fails because the tarballs doesn't have the `py` or `PyInfo` provider .
# If I use a `pkg_tar` rule here, the tarball has exactly the contents I'd want to have as a python library.
py_library(
    name = "python",
    deps = [
        ":python_domain_tarball",
        ":python_messages_tarball",
    ],
)
```

I've found some places that say that this can be solved by putting the `messages.proto` file inside the directory structure in the same place as I want the generated file to wind up. That sounds like a bad workaround, considering that placement won't make any sense for any other language than Python. I also generate a java package, and in the future the plan is to add other languages too.

Is this simply a limitation of Bazel, or can it be solved in some fancy way that I haven't been able to google my way to?

Comment: I think pkg_tar is a dead end. Maybe https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/master/docs/copy_file_doc.md helps?

Answer (score 0):

With the link provided by [Sjoerd Visscher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360261/combine-protobuf-with-python-namespaced-package-in-bazel?noredirect=1#comment113823432_64360261), I found a solution that seems to do the trick. First step was to separate into language specific packages. Then use `copy_file` to move the generated file into a subdirectory. Once that was done, combining the helper files with the generated file in a `py_library` was pretty straight forward.

The file layout is now:

```
.
├── protobuf
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── messages.proto
└── python
    ├── BUILD
    └── ibidem
        ├── __init__.py
        └── codetanks
            ├── __init__.py
            └── domain
                └── __init__.py
```

Contents of `protobuf/BUILD`:

```
package(default_visibility=["//domain:__subpackages__"])

load("@build_stack_rules_proto//python:python_proto_library.bzl", "python_proto_library")

proto_library(
    name = "messages_proto",
    srcs = ["messages.proto"],
)

python_proto_library(
    name = "python_messages_proto",
    deps = [":messages_proto"],
)
```

Contents of `python/BUILD`:

```
load("@build_stack_rules_proto//python:python_proto_library.bzl", "python_proto_library")
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library")
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:copy_file.bzl", "copy_file")

copy_file(
    name="python_messages_file",
    src="//domain/protobuf:python_messages_proto",
    out="ibidem/codetanks/domain/messages_pb2.py",
)

filegroup(
    name = "python_helper_files",
    srcs = glob([
        "ibidem/**/__init__.py",
    ]),
)

py_library(
    name = "messages",
    srcs = [
        ":python_helper_files",
        ":python_messages_file",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```